# Выбор трека через Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Нужно сделать выбор файла(трека) из стороннего приложения.
Например так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для открытия диалога выбора файла я нашел что нужно использовать Intent, но я не пойму какую категорию лучше использовать.

Если использовать следующий код:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("audio/*");
 Intent fileIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Выбор файла");
 startActivityForResult(intent,123);
```

то выводиться следующее окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел правильный `ACTION` для выбора трека, вот код который у меня работает:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); 
Intent fileIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Выбор файла"); 
startActivityForResult(fileIntent,123);
```